# Is it possible to detect an onclick event immediately following an onchange event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- HTML5 -->
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
</head>

<body>
<p><button type="button" onclick="show()">Show new name</button></p>
<p>Name: <input type="text" onchange="changed()" id ="nm" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"></p>
<p>New name: <span id="sh" ></span></p>

<script>
function show()
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("nm");
    name = elem.value;
    document.getElementById("sh").innerHTML = name;
}
function changed()
{
    alert("Name changed");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If the user types in a new name, changes focus, and then clicks the button the new name is displayed as intended.
However, if the user changes the name and then clicks the button without changing the focus, the new name is not displayed.
Why is this? In my code there are several inputs, and I would like to process each at the time it is changed, and then do something more when the button is clicked. The problem is that the button click is not recognized unless the user first makes a non-intuitive mouse click or presses <kbd>enter</kbd>. Is there a way to get the desired behavior?

Comment: Please never use inline javascript (in your html: onclick, onchange). That has never been a good practice.

Comment: @m59 I understand. My purpose here was to frame the issue in the simplist possible way.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is the alert.

The click event fires when one mousedown and one mouseup has been detected on the element.

When you press the button mousedown is fired and the blur on the input, which triggers the onchange event. But it adds an alert who came in front (between your cursor and the button, so the mouseup never fires on the button, nor the onclick).

To avoid this you can :

- remove the alert (and all will be working fine)
- Register onmousedown on the button and not onclick.

Comment: "Register onmousedown on the button and not onclick"

Comment: "Register onmousedown on the button and not onclick" This is brilliant, and does exactly what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly get what you want to achieve. But if you just want to change the name after the button click with the focus still being in the input, just change your "onchange" function to show()

```
<p><button type="button" onclick="show()">Show new name</button></p>
<p>Name: <input type="text" onchange="show()" id ="nm" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"></p>
<p>New name: <span id="sh" ></span></p>
```

[example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TSbm4/)

And as m59 stated, inline JavaScript is never a good practice.

Comment: I want to be able to change several inputs without calling "show()" each time, and then have "show()" called when the user clicks the button after typing in the last input (but without the need to make an extra mouse click or press "enter" just to lose the focus before clicking on the button.

Answer (score 0):

The `onchange` event occurs when the value of an element has been changed and the `onclick` event occurs when the user clicks on an element.

I suggest you to use `onblur` event.Try this:

```
<p>Name: <input type="text" onblur="changed()" id ="nm" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"></p>
```

The onblur event occurs when an object loses focus.

Check here:[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkF7Q/)